# Linking to another page in an if else statement in php

Tags: php

So I'd like to link my Login page to another page if the mysql database returns with a result. I have a login page and the invalid email and checking with the database part works fine the result is negative, I just want it to link to another page if a result comes out

```
<?php

include 'dbconnect.php';
$emailErr = "";
$email    = "";
$message  = "";


if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (empty($_POST["email1"])) {
        $emailErr = "Email is required";
    } else {
        $email = test_input($_POST["email1"]);
    }
    // check if e-mail address is well-formed
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $emailErr = "Invalid email format";
    }

    else {
        $connection = connect();
        $sql        = "SELECT First_Name, Last_name FROM Potential_Employee WHERE Email='$email'";
        $result     = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
        $row        = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) === 0) {
            $message = "Sorry, there is no record of that email address in our database";
        } else {



            //I WANT THIS TO LINK TO ANOTHER PAGE(I.E A DASHBOARD) IF THE DATABASE GOT A RESULT.


        }
        mysqli_free_result($result);
        mysqli_close($connection);
    }

}

function test_input($data)
{
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}
?>
```

Comment: use a prepared statement and do away with that awful `test_input()` method. That will not safeguard you against a potential sql injection.

Comment: what do you mean by "link to another page"?

Comment: what do you mean with "link"? you want to redirect user to another page or to load here some html from other php file?

Comment: and your login method is scary. Imagine if someone guesses an existing email? I hope for your sake that this isn't a live site or intended to go live; not with that anyway.

Comment: what do you want to do exactly? linking to another page or what? If loading another page, use can use                                                                                                                       echo "<script>document.location='new_page.php';</script>";

Comment: you gotta love unresponsiveness eh? well good luck, I'll pass on this one; *bye*

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what do you mean by linking it with another page, but I would assume you would like to either include another page in there or redirect a user to a dashboard.

Redirect with

```
header('location:your_page');exit;
```

Or if you'd like to display content right there, just use include function.

However, I assume you would like to keep the info of logged in user across several page and to restrict access to non-logged in visitors. To do so, I would suggest to set some session variables which you can check against on each page that requires user to be logged in.
For example:

```
$_SESSION['ses_user_id'] = 'user id from db result';
```

And on page which requires user to be logged in, you would just check if the session with ses_user_id is set or not.

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['ses_user_id']))
  header('location:login_page');
```

If I missunderstood your question, sorry.

Comment: Oh I'm trying to redirect, except when I press submit in my form, I tried it your way but a blank screen loads and it doesnt link to the page I asked it to link to. Any clue why? Apologies for being unclear in the question

Comment: Do you have error showing on? Are you sure your script is not returning any errors?
Does it goes into an else part of the if where you want redirection?

Comment: Nothing happens, once I press the submit button, the link in the browser stays the same, but the whole page turns blank. However, if i used what someone else suggested to me which was:
echo "<script>document.location='new_page.php';</script>";

it goes to the new page. Although I would rather not use javascript in my php part.

Comment: `header('location:name_of_your_page_where_you_redirect.php');` doesn't work?

Comment: Where exactly did you put `echo "<script>document.location='new_page.php';</script>";`?
Can you paste part of the code that you tried with header function?

Comment: Where i commented:
 //I WANT THIS TO LINK TO ANOTHER PAGE(I.E A DASHBOARD) IF THE DATABASE GOT A RESULT.

Comment: If you can't figure it out don't worry about it, I can use the script one for now and see if my lecturer can help me the next time I see her. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you sure there is no ouput to the browser before you are doing redirect? That includes a white space as well, which will prevent header location to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you're asking for:

```
else {
    header('Location: nameoftheotherlink.php');
    exit();
}
```